# How to convert blog rss which has images/text into native android app with phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, html, cordova

I want an app with recent post in my blog and a synchronization option. It will store everything in local storage. I am able to store text as json object in local memory but I don't know how to download and store images from url to phone memory...

I have tried using fileTransfer.download and one phonegap plugin to download files

I am testing my app in emulator. I don't know where to store these images and how to store them so that they are permanent.

Answer (score 0):

They can never be permanent you are **NOT** a system app. And by this I mean storing it in data forever. However; you have the option of storing stuff on the SDCARD, which will last as long as the user does not delete your data. **THIS** cannot be permanent is dependent on the user's card/choice to do whatever they wish to the files on **THEIR** SDCARD.

Comment: Can you please tell how do I store data in sdcard. I want to store images and one json file in sdcard that will be fetched by my app to display the blog posts.

Comment: there are tons of examples of this, try looking it up.. json or not.. its data doesn't matter.